# Swift, Firebase - Present different ViewControllers in AppDelegate if User is Logged-in

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm using Firebase for my app and I want to present different view controllers in AppDelegate with the code below but I keep getting an error.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow()
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            window?.rootViewController = HomeController()
        } else {
            window?.rootViewController = LoginController()
        }

    return true

    }

    ...
```

This is the error.

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException
>       (lldb)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! Looks like "FirebaseApp.configure()" was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that you need a reference to the already created instance instead of creating a new one. There can be two case

Case 1. If you want to change the initial view controller on the check of if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil or iAuth.auth().currentUser != nil then you can simply write the code in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* in AppDelegate and make sure you must give the identifier in storyboard and use the same identifier in the code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   let mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
       let viewcontroller :  MainViewController = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewIdentifier") as! MainViewController
       self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
       self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
    } else {
       let viewcontroller :  LoginViewController = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewIdentifier") as! LoginViewController
       self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
       self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
    }

return true

}
```

Case 2. Suppose you have Main/Home/Dash VC (View controller) and it’s always is the initial view controller then there you have implemented the check *if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil*  then present/push the Login view controller else not.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.0**

You can use this function as like below in `AppDelegate`.

```
func configureWindowAndMakeVisible(rootVC: UIViewController) {
        if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
            window.rootViewController = rootVC
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
      }
  }

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            // Use initialization (i.e HomeController()) only if you had initialize view in Controller
            configureWindowAndMakeVisible(rootVC: HomeController()) 
        } else {
            configureWindowAndMakeVisible(rootVC: LoginController()) 
        }

    return true
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are Direct Creating New Instance of ViewController
Try the following code

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            var mainView: UIStoryboard!
        mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let viewcontroller :  HomeController = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController") as! HomeController
        self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
        } else {
                     var mainView: UIStoryboard!
        mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)
         let viewcontroller :  LoginController = mainView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVCIdentifier") as! LoginController
        self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
        }

    return true

    }
```

Make Sure you have given identifier to controller from storyboard